# Alignment of equations using align and split

Tags: align, split

I have a larger set of equations and I can't manage to format the equations correctly.

- The first line of each equation should be left-aligned (maybe this is done automatically?).
- The other lines of each equation should be right-aligned with the first line.

See image (example for 2 equations). I hope that I'm making sense.

[image]

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \epsilon^2\partial_{\textnormal{t}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}\cdot\nabla_{\textnormal{h}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2w\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\Tilde{\pi}+\gamma\Bar{\pi}\left(\nabla_{\textnormal{h}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}+\frac{1}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left(\Bar{p}w\right)\right) \\
        +\epsilon^2\gamma\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\left(\nabla_{\textnormal{h}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}+\partial_{\textnormal{z}}w\right)=\frac{\gamma{\color{red}\pi}}{\Theta}Q_{\Theta}\,,
    \end{split}
    \\[4ex]
    \begin{split}
        \epsilon^2\left(\epsilon\partial_{\textnormal{t}_\textnormal{m}}+\epsilon^2\partial_{\textnormal{t}_\textnormal{s}}\right)\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}\cdot\left(\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\right)\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2\left(\epsilon\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon^2\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\Tilde{\pi} \\
        +\gamma\Bar{\pi}\left(\left(\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}\cdot\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\right)\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}+\frac{1}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left(\Bar{p}\left(\epsilon\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon^2\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\right)\right) \\
        +\epsilon^2\gamma\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\left(\left(\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\right)\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}+\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left(\right)\epsilon\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon^2\,w_{2}+\dots\right)=\frac{\gamma{\color{red}\left(\Bar{\pi}+\epsilon^2\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\right)}}{1+\epsilon\Bar{\Theta}+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\Theta}}\left(\epsilon^2\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}Q_{\Theta,2}+\epsilon^3Q_{\Theta,3}+\dots\right)\,, 
    \end{split}
    \\[4ex]
    \begin{split}
        \epsilon^3\partial_{\textnormal{t}_\textnormal{m}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^4\partial_{\textnormal{t}_\textnormal{s}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^3\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)\cdot\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^4\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)\cdot\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^3\left(\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\Tilde{\pi} \\
        +\gamma\Bar{\pi}\left(\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)+\frac{\epsilon}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left[\Bar{p}\left(\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\right]\right) \\
        +\epsilon^2\gamma\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\left[\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)+\epsilon\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left(\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\right] \\
        =\frac{\gamma{\color{red}\left(\Bar{\pi}+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\pi}\right)}}{1+\epsilon\Bar{\Theta}+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\Theta}}\left(\epsilon^2\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}Q_{\Theta,2}+\epsilon^3Q_{\Theta,3}+\dots\right)\,.
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

You don't have to change the brackets or Bar and Tilde, I know they're not ideal

Comment: the intended markup here is `multline` as you need no `&` (which does left,center,right rather than left then right)  certainly avoid `split` here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
Could you provide a simple example? I have never used multiline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no alignment points here (so no `&`) so neither `align` nor `split` should be used. `multline` is intended for single long lines that need to be wrapped.  Here as you have several I put them in a `gather` and used the nested version `multlined` (from `mathtools`).

It's still a bit ugly but you can more easly adjust the line breaks to reflect the meaning.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \begin{multlined}
        \epsilon^2\partial_{\mathrm{t}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}\cdot\nabla_{\mathrm{h}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2w\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\Tilde{\pi}+\gamma\Bar{\pi}\bigl(\nabla_{\mathrm{h}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}+\frac{1}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\bigl(\Bar{p}w\bigr)\bigr) \\
        +\epsilon^2\gamma\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\bigl(\nabla_{\mathrm{h}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}+\partial_{\mathrm{z}}w\bigr)
        \\=\frac{\gamma{\color{red}\pi}}{\Theta}Q_{\Theta}\,,
        \end{multlined}
        \\[10pt]
        \begin{multlined}
        \epsilon^2\bigl(\epsilon\partial_{\mathrm{t}_\mathrm{m}}+\epsilon^2\partial_{\mathrm{t}_\mathrm{s}}\bigr)\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}\cdot\bigl(\epsilon\nabla_{\mathrm{m}}+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\mathrm{s}}\bigr)\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2\bigl(\epsilon\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon^2\,w_{2}+\dots\bigr)\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\Tilde{\pi} \\
        +\gamma\Bar{\pi}\bigl(\bigl(\epsilon\nabla_{\mathrm{m}}\cdot\epsilon^2\nabla_{\mathrm{s}}\bigr)\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}+\frac{1}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\bigl(\Bar{p}\bigl(\epsilon\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon^2\,w_{2}+\dots\bigr)\bigr)\bigr) \\
        +\epsilon^2\gamma\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\bigl(\bigl(\epsilon\nabla_{\mathrm{m}}+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\mathrm{s}}\bigr)\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h}}+\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\bigl(\bigr)\epsilon\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon^2\,w_{2}+\dots\bigr)\\
        =\frac{\gamma{\color{red}\bigl(\Bar{\pi}+\epsilon^2\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\bigr)}}{1+\epsilon\Bar{\Theta}+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\Theta}}\bigl(\epsilon^2\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}Q_{\Theta,2}+\epsilon^3Q_{\Theta,3}+\dots\bigr)\,, 
    \end{multlined}\raisetag{45pt}
    \\[10pt]
    \begin{multlined}
      \epsilon^3\partial_{\mathrm{t}_\mathrm{m}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^4\partial_{\mathrm{t}_\mathrm{s}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^3\bigl(\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,1}}+\dots\bigr)\cdot\nabla_{\mathrm{m}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^4\bigl(\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,1}}+\dots\bigr)\cdot\\
      \nabla_{\mathrm{s}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^3\bigl(\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon\,w_{2}+\dots\bigr)\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\Tilde{\pi} \\
      +\gamma\Bar{\pi}\bigl(\epsilon\nabla_{\mathrm{m}}\cdot\bigl(\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,1}}+\dots\bigr)+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\mathrm{s}}\cdot\bigl(\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,1}}+\dots\bigr)+\\
      \frac{\epsilon}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\bigl[\Bar{p}\bigl(\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon\,w_{2}+\dots\bigr)\bigr]\bigr) \\
        +\epsilon^2\gamma\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\bigl[\epsilon\nabla_{\mathrm{m}}\cdot\bigr(\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,1}}+\dots\bigr)+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\mathrm{s}}\cdot\\
          \Bigl(\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{h,1}}+\dots\bigr)+\epsilon\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\bigl(\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon\,w_{2}+\dots\bigr)\bigr] \\
        =\frac{\gamma{\color{red}\bigl(\Bar{\pi}+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\pi}\bigr)}}{1+\epsilon\Bar{\Theta}+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\Theta}}\bigl(\epsilon^2\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}Q_{\Theta,2}+\epsilon^3Q_{\Theta,3}+\dots\bigr)\,.\raisetag{60pt}
  \end{multlined}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Gather is great.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
    &\begin{aligned}
        \epsilon^2\partial_{\textnormal{t}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}\cdot\nabla_{\textnormal{h}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2w\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\Tilde{\pi}+\gamma\Bar{\pi}\left(\nabla_{\textnormal{h}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}+\frac{1}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left(\Bar{p}w\right)\right)& \\
        +\epsilon^2\gamma\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\left(\nabla_{\textnormal{h}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}+\partial_{\textnormal{z}}w\right)=\frac{\gamma{\color{red}\pi}}{\Theta}Q_{\Theta}\,,&
    \end{aligned}
    \\[4ex]
    &\begin{aligned}
        \epsilon^2\left(\epsilon\partial_{\textnormal{t}_\textnormal{m}}+\epsilon^2\partial_{\textnormal{t}_\textnormal{s}}\right)\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}\cdot\left(\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\right)\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^2\left(\epsilon\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon^2\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\Tilde{\pi}& \\
        +\gamma\Bar{\pi}\left(\left(\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}\cdot\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\right)\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}+\frac{1}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left(\Bar{p}\left(\epsilon\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon^2\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\right)\right)& \\
        +\epsilon^2\gamma\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\left(\left(\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\right)\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h}}+\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left(\right)\epsilon\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon^2\,w_{2}+\dots\right)& \\
        =\frac{\gamma{\color{red}\left(\Bar{\pi}+\epsilon^2\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\right)}}{1+\epsilon\Bar{\Theta}+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\Theta}}\left(\epsilon^2\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}Q_{\Theta,2}+\epsilon^3Q_{\Theta,3}+\dots\right)\,,& 
    \end{aligned}
    \\[4ex]
    &\begin{aligned}
        \epsilon^3\partial_{\textnormal{t}_\textnormal{m}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^4\partial_{\textnormal{t}_\textnormal{s}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^3\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)\cdot\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^4\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)\cdot\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\Tilde{\pi}+\epsilon^3\left(\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\Tilde{\pi}& \\
        +\gamma\Bar{\pi}\left(\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)+\frac{\epsilon}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left[\Bar{p}\left(\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\right]\right)& \\
        +\epsilon^2\gamma\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\left[\epsilon\nabla_{\textnormal{m}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)+\epsilon^2\nabla_{\textnormal{s}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,0}}+\epsilon\mathbf{v}_{\textnormal{h,1}}+\dots\right)+\epsilon\partial_{\textnormal{z}}\left(\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}w_{1}+\epsilon\,w_{2}+\dots\right)\right]& \\
        =\frac{\gamma{\color{red}\left(\Bar{\pi}+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\pi}\right)}}{1+\epsilon\Bar{\Theta}+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\Theta}}\left(\epsilon^2\alpha_{\textnormal{w}}Q_{\Theta,2}+\epsilon^3Q_{\Theta,3}+\dots\right)\,.&
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works for you?? How wide is your page? You only showed a fragment so it's hard to tell. Using the standard classes  this is almost 120pt too wide and completely off the page, you also changed to unnumbered here and had numbered in the question.  leaving space for the numbers makes it even harder to make this fit, which is why I had to have more lines.

Comment: I don't know... Where can I see the page width?

Comment: just look at your output document, also your log file probably has something like `Overfull \hbox (117.23682pt too wide) detected at line 60`  If you add text before your equation you will see it fits in the area marked `X...X` on the image I added to this answer. which is using the document preamble that you used in the question but for some reason removed here.